# parsing data in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, navigation

Hello I'm learning react-native, I made pages order and detail
here I make a function on the order page

```
ongNavigationDetail = ()=>{
        let params = {
            origin: this.state.selectOrigin.id_origin,
            destinasi : this.state.selectSubDestinasi.id_destinasi
        }
        this.props.navigation.push('detail',{data:params})
    }

     <View style={styles.Button}>
        <Button block info style={styles.MainBtn} onPress={this.ongNavigationDetail}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Next</Text>
        </Button>
     </View>
```

here I throw the value from the order page to the detail page, the question is how to take the value on the detail page?

I use react navigation 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still using React Navigation 4.X try out something like this:

```
navigation.getParam('someParam', 'defaultValue');
```

someParam ofc would be data in your case. Remeber to add this.props. before the code if it is needed.

Comment: can give an example ?

Comment: let testVar = this.props.navigation.getParam("data"); then you should be able to call console.log(testVar) somewhere and it should hold the passed data